Django ORM efficient way for annotating True on first occurrences of field
I have a situation where we have some logic that sorts a patient_journey queryset (table) by some heuristics. A patient_journey has a FK to a patient.
I now need an efficient way of setting True for the first occurrence of a patient_journey for a given patient, false otherwise.
The first heuristinc is patient_id so the queryset will already by grouped by patient.
The algorithm is v straight forward & should be fast, yet I'm stuck at trying to get something <1s.
I've tried using distinct and checking for existence, however that's adding 1-2s.
I've tried using a subquery with [:1] & test on id, but that's even worse around 3-5s extra.
Currently most efficient approach:

cost of get_sorted_for_primary_journey_qs is minimal, the distinct & exists is expensive, all I want is the first occurrence of patient_id on patient_journey to be marked as primary=True

def annotate_primary(
    *, qs: QuerySet['PatientJourney']  # noqa
) -> QuerySet['PatientJourney']:  # noqa
    """
    Constraints:
    --------------
    Exactly One non-global primary journey per patient

    Annotations:
    ------------
    is_primary_:Bool, is the primary_journey for a patient
    """
    from patient_journey.models import PatientJourney
    sorted_pjs = get_sorted_for_primary_journey_qs(qs=qs)
    sorted_pjs = sorted_pjs.distinct('patient_id').values('id')
    pjs = PatientJourney.objects.all().filter(id__in=sorted_pjs)
    qs = qs.annotate(
        primary=dm.Exists(
            pjs.filter(
                id=dm.OuterRef('id'),
            )
        )
    )
    return qs


Can you add your models with minimal fields to understand what you need..I think a subquery could do the job

@Dante I've added the most efficient current implementation I found.
If you can think of something better than this, do throw your ideas at me.
Using a Sub-query with .values('id')[:1] to match on outer ref id is much slower than this.

Assuming the models are like this
from django.db import models

class Patient(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  
class PatientJourney(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='journeys')
    visit_date = models.DateTimeField()
    diagnosis = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    treatment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    


Using Window funstions you can get only the first journeys
from django.db.models import Window, F
from django.db.models.functions import RowNumber
from .models import PatientJourney

# Annotate each journey with its row number partitioned by patient and ordered by visit_date in ascendin order
patient_journeys_with_row_number = PatientJourney.objects.annotate(
    row_number=Window(
        expression=RowNumber(),
        partition_by=[F('patient')],
        order_by=F('visit_date').asc()
    )
).filter(row_number=1)

for journey in patient_journeys_with_row_number:
    print(f"{journey.patient.first_name} {journey.patient.last_name} - First Journey on {journey.visit_date}")

